# System.nanoTime() on windows XP

Tags: java, time

I just found [System.currentTimeMillis is not accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859019/system-currenttimemillis-is-not-accurate-on-windows-xp) on windows XP, now I tried `System.nanoTime()` with the same code.

Since `1ms = 1,000,000ns`, so I think the result should be `15,000,000ns`, but it's not.

See the sample code:

```
public class NanoTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = 0;
        long end = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (start == 0) {
                start = System.nanoTime();
            } else {
                long current = System.nanoTime();
                if (current != start) {
                    end = current;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The time interval of your OS: " + (end - start) + "ns");
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
The time interval of your OS: 655ns
```

Seems it's much better than `System.currentTimeMillis()`. But why? Can we believe this result?

Comment: simply: `interval = System.nanoTime() - System.nanoTime()`

Comment: nanoTime doesn't time itself against a clock it just counts clock cycles, synchronised using the power management (APM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Windows XP has SP3 then you can believe that result... on Windows the JVM implements `nanoTime()` **internally** using `QueryPerformanceCounter/QueryPerformanceFrequency` API which is basically located in HAL (Hardware abstraction layer) and uses some CPU-internal *interval* instructions which are rather accurate... it is only good for *interval measurements* NOT for time handling...

For a more elaborate description see http://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks and http://juliusdavies.ca/posix_clocks/clock_realtime_linux_faq.html

**EDIT - as per comment:**

The above mentioned function are used by the JVM itself internally when `nanoTime` is called which has absolutely NOTHING to do with JNI - they are not exposed to Java code!

**EDIT 2 - as per comments:**

`nanoTime()` is the right tool to measure *elapsed time* accurately while `currentTimeMillis` is the right tool to handle *absolute time*.

Comment: Which are both not avaliable in Java unless using JNI

Comment: the JVM uses them INTERNALLY when you call `nanoTime()`!

Comment: @Yahia, thank you, your answer is different from JonSkeet's, I don't know should I believe it or not -_-##

Comment: Per your answer, we should always use `System.nanoTime()` if we want a accurate elapsed time which may be less than `10ms`?

Comment: @Freewind where do you see the difference ? In my answer I explain why it is technically accurate while Jon Skeet writes that it good to "measuring elapsed time (not absolute time)" which is the same I write (i.e. interval measurement)...

Comment: @Freewind Jon Skeet writes that `nanoTime` is good for measuring elapsed time accurately - same as I write... follow the links in my answer and see for yourself what Oracle writes about this

Comment: My misunderstanding, sorry. I think I understand now. If the elapsed time is huge, that we can use both "System.currentTimeMillis" and "nanoTime". If it's small (less than 10ms), we'd better use `nanoTime`. And the result of `655ns` is accurate enough, we can trust it's really `665ns`

Comment: yes... see the comment from Jon Skeet below... he clarifies and writes the same...

Answer (score 4):

> Why?

Because it's not trying to be accurate in the same way.

From the Javadocs:

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time.

So yes, it's good for measuring elapsed time accurately. It's not good at giving you an absolute time, and you won't get that more accurately than `System.currentTimeMillis()`, at least without coordinating explicitly with NTP etc. Use the right tool for the job, and don't design a system which needs a hugely accurate absolute time.

Comment: thanks again. So there is no difference if we use `nanotime` or `millistime` to measure the elapsed time? The result `655ns` doesn't mean `0.000655ms`?

Comment: @Freewind: No, there's a big difference. If you want to measure *elapsed time*, you *should* use `nanotime`, because it's more accurate than `currentTimeMillis`. You use `currentTimeMillis` for *absolute* times. As I say, use each method for what it was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know what a method does is to read [its javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29). Not to guess what it does using experiments.

> Returns the current value of the most precise available system timer,
>   in nanoseconds.
>
> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not
>   related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value
>   returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time
>   (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). This method
>   provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond
>   accuracy. No guarantees are made about how frequently values change.

Comment: thanks, it's useful, but does not have enough information I want.